# Как увеличить максимальный размер вложения загружаемого на сервер в iis express?

Tags: asp.net-core, iis-express

При переносе проекта с asp.net web api на asp.net core web api столкнулся с проблемой ограничения максимального размера вложения, в старой версии в web.config надо было добавить следующее правило

```
<requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="536870912" />
```

в секцию system.webServer -> security -> requestFiltering, где 536870912 максимальный размер в байтах, в созданном же проекте файл web.config отсутствует, для отладки используется iis express, как увеличить максимальный размер вложения для asp.net core web api?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для того что бы увеличить максимальный размер вложения при отладке приложения через iis express необходимо внести изменения в файл `applicationhost.config`

```
<system.webServer>
    <security>
        <requestFiltering>    
            <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="536870912" />
        </requestFiltering>
    </security>
</system.webServer>
```

который в моем случае был по следующему пути `имя проекта\.vs\имя проекта\config\applicationhost.config`, так же потребовалось добавить два фильтра на метод отвечающий за сохранение файла на сервере

```
[RequestFormLimits(MultipartBodyLengthLimit = 536870912)]
[RequestSizeLimit(536870912)]
public async Task<ActionResult> AddItem()
{
}
```