# В IFormFile прилетает null

Tags: c#, asp.net

Есть такой тестовый метод контроллера

```
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> UploadFile(IFormFile file)
    {
        if (file == null || file.Length == 0)
            return Content("file not selected");

        var ms = new MemoryStream();
        file.OpenReadStream().CopyTo(ms);
        byte[] fileBytes = ms.ToArray();

        try
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"ClamAV scan begin for file {file.FileName}");
            var clam = new ClamClient("localhost", 3310);
            var scanResult = await clam.SendAndScanFileAsync(fileBytes);
            switch (scanResult.Result)
            {
                case ClamScanResults.Clean:
                    Console.WriteLine($"The file is clean! ScanResult: {scanResult.RawResult}");
                    break;
                case ClamScanResults.VirusDetected:
                    Console.WriteLine($"Virus Found! Virus name: {scanResult.InfectedFiles.FirstOrDefault().VirusName}");
                    break;
                case ClamScanResults.Error:
                    Console.WriteLine($"An error occurred while scanning the file! ScanResult: {scanResult.RawResult}");
                    break;
                case ClamScanResults.Unknown:
                    Console.WriteLine($"Unknown scan result while scanning the file! ScanResult: {scanResult.RawResult}");
                    break;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"ClamAV Scan Exception: {ex.Message}");
        }

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

который принимает файл на сканирование, он принимает IFormFile, и с файлами до 20мб+- все нормально, они загружаются и сканируются, но когда я пытаюсь загрузить файл весом в 47мб мне в IFormFile прилетает null, пробовал ставить небольшую задержку(не знаю на что надеялся), пытался добавлять такое в класс Program

```
        builder.Services.Configure<FormOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.MultipartBodyLengthLimit = 100 * 1024 * 1024;
        });
```

Но это тоже не помогло, и скорее всего дело в ограничении веса файла, как тут :

[Как увеличить максимальный размер вложения загружаемого на сервер в iis express?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1428558/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%83%d0%b2%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d0%ba%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b0%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%80-%d0%b2%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b3%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b6%d0%b0%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d1%81%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80-%d0%b2-iis-express?rq=1)

Но, у меня просто напросто нет этого файла на который ссылаются в ответе, и XML файлов в проекте вообще нет. Подскажите что нужно сделать...

Comment: Какая версия ASP.NET?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/62608746/5045688

Comment: Там настройки надо сделать в веб-сервисе, это известная проблема. По ссылке в комментарии в частности написано, да.

Comment: .net 7.0
В решении которое вы скинули эта проблема фиксится через файл конфигурации, которого у меня нет.
 @AlexanderPetrov

Comment: Это наверное NET Framework 7.0, а вот ASP.NET какой версии? Там всё отдельно кажется версионируется.

Comment: Если скажете где находится версия, то скажу, пока что я вижу только. 
    <TargetFramework>net7.0</TargetFramework>

А еще я посмотрел web.config создается только в проектах ASP.NET Web App (.NET Framework), а у меня проект на ASP.NET Web APP (.NET 7.0) @CrazyElf

Comment: @air если вы используете iis, то web.config у вас совершенно точно есть. Это, всё-таки, файл конфигурации iis. Вам нужно лишь разобраться как правильно добавить его в проект.

Comment: @air а вот если вы используете голый Kestrel - то в сторону web.config можете даже не смотреть

Comment: @PavelMayorov Я как раз таки Kestrel и использую. Поэтому и спрашиваю, как можно убрать ограничение.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте в `Program.cs` добавить:

```cs
builder.WebHost.ConfigureKestrel(options => 
{ 
    options.Limits.MaxRequestBodySize = 100 * 1024 * 1024; 
});
```

или использовать `[RequestSizeLimit(100 * 1024 * 1024)]` аттрибут на вашем контроллере.

Comment: В таком случае кидает исключение "The maximum stream size of 26214400 bytes has been exceeded."

Comment: @air вооооот, это уже другая проблема!

Comment: @PavelMayorov Ну конечно, теперь null не прилетает, но оно все равно не работет. xDD

Comment: @air если вам null не прилетает - значит, не работает уже ваш собственный код. Значит, вы можете выяснить в какой строчке ошибка.

Comment: @air исправлять нужно по одной ошибке за раз, и тогда в конечном итоге вы исправите все. А если отказываться исправлять одну ошибку на основании наличия второй - вы никогда не исправите ни одной из них.

Comment: @air в любом случае, вторая ошибка уже не имеет никакого отношения к исходному вопросу (проблема там вообще не в ASP.NET, а в ClamClient). Так что проявите вежливость и отметьте ответ как полезный вам.

Comment: @PavelMayorov С чего вы взяли что проблема в ClamClient, изначально ошибка была в том что в качестве агрумента прилетает null, вместо IFormFile, а сейчас прилетает IFormFile, но все же файл не загружается на сервер из-за ограничения размера файла. Но согласен, вопрос который я задал, отчасти решен, но тот null который приходил, был неявным результатом этого самого ограничения размера. Так что отчасти проблема не решена, но это уже моя проблема, я неправильно составил вопрос.

Comment: @PavelMayorov Было бы вежливо принять ответ как правильный. Но что увидит другой человек с такой же проблемой ? Увидит что вопрос принят, и он "решает проблему", навряд ли он будет читать комментарии, но когда вставит этот код, будет немного удивлен, тому что теперь вместо одной ошибки, у него вылезает другая.

Comment: @air с того, что у другого человека второй проблемы, скорее всего, просто не возникнет - ведь он не использует ClamClient

Comment: @air а про ClamClient я взял с того, что именно у него в настройках есть этот самый "maximum stream size". В то время как в исходниках ASP.NET Core полученное вами сообщение об ошибке отсутствует в принципе.

Comment: @PavelMayorov Точно, я был не прав. Сейчас отмечу ответ принятым, я просто совершенно забыл что это не мой основной контроллер, и он не загружает файлы на сервер).

Comment: @air на будущее: научитесь читать стектрейсы исключений. Они очень хорошо показывают где именно ошибка, если бы вы его прочитали - вам бы даже не понадобились услуги телепата (в моём лице).